# jQuery draggable (and sortable) with CSS-Image replacement (FiR) causes image to 'disappear'

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have a two columns and am able to drag and drop items between the two lists. This works when it displays text. When I use the FiR technique to replace the text with an image (through CSS) and then drag the item from one column to the next, the item disappears (no image shown, but a blank area the size of the image is there). When I drag an item over the top of that item the image reappears. This image 'disappears' on any drop.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/Proveniebam/8X9xf/

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of looking around I had to make the draggable object make use of the 'clone' helper.